# Item_search not returning all offers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm using the item_search method of the amazon product api, but noticed that even though the total number of offers returned can be pretty high, not all the offers are returned by item_search. Is there a way to get item_search to return all the offers? I'm using the 'Large' response group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [OfferFull](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_OfferFull.html) response group to get a full page of offers (10 offers per page).

The `TotalOfferPages` node returned in the response shows how many pages of offers there are.  To get a particular page, set the `OfferPage` request parameter to a number less than or equal to `TotalOfferPages`.

For example, this pseudo request would get the second `OfferPage`:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=1451648537&
Condition=All&
ResponseGroup=OfferFull&
OfferPage=2&                    <- parameter that controls the OfferPage number
Version=2009-03-31&
Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]&
Signature=[Request Signature]
```